# Issue with while getting item information of sales order in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

i'm trying to get salesorder records based on date...i'm getting primary information and some sales information also..but while trying to get item details getting null of SalesOrderItemList....but i tried for individual record i'm getting data.

help to solve this one...

```
  Calendar fromDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -15);
        SearchDateField searchDateField=new SearchDateField();
        searchDateField.setOperator(SearchDateFieldOperator.after);
        searchDateField.setSearchValue(fromDate);
        TransactionSearchBasic tsb=new TransactionSearchBasic();
         tsb.setDateCreated(searchDateField);
        SearchResult res = _port.search(tsb);
        RecordList rl=res.getRecordList();
        Record[] rr=rl.getRecord();
        String salesord=null;
        for(Record rcd:rr){
            salesord=rcd.getClass().getName();
            System.out.println("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk :"+salesord);

            if(rcd instanceof SalesOrder){
                SalesOrder so=(SalesOrder)rcd;
                if(so.getSalesRep()!=null){
                System.out.println("slaesorder  "+                                       (so.getSalesRep().getName())+"555555 :"+so.getSubsidiary().getName());
                }
              if(so.getItemList()!=null){
                SalesOrderItemList itemlist=(so.getItemList());
                System.out.println("temlist");
                SalesOrderItem[] items=itemlist.getItem();
                if(items!=null){
                    System.out.println("if items");
                for(SalesOrderItem item:items)
                {
                                System.out.println(item.getItem().getName()+"  "+item.getQuantity()+"   "+item.getDescription()+"  "+item.getQuantityOnHand());
                }
                }

            }

            }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something changed with NetSuite yesterday or last night(2014-05-09). It's not returning the sub data like it should when you specify `bodyFieldsOnly = false` in the search preferences.

I've been pulling transactions now for over a year and this just stopped working this morning. Nothing in our php library/code has changed.

I'm not seeing that `bodyFieldsOnly` parameter set in your code, so you will need to do that. The default is true which only returns the top level sales order information.